# div won't stop automatically scrolling between refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div filled with enough elements that makes the scroll bar appear.

I scroll down half way and then refresh the page.

The div is now empty so it has no scroll bar since its set to

```
overflow:auto
```

Then I set the div to reset its scroll position with

```
$(".myclass")[0].scrollTop = 0;
```

Then I add the elements to the div again and it scrolls back to the halfway mark that it was at before the refresh emptied it.

It seems that the div ignores the command to set the scroll if the scrollbar is not visible and active.

How can I set the position of the scrollbar back to the top while it is empty?

edit: I made a really hacky solution by adding a massive div to make the scrollbar appear and then I remove it after I set the scrollTop to zero, but there should be a better solution than that.

Comment: Is there a way you could reproduce the problem in a snippet on jsfiddle or codepen so we can visualize it? Does setting overflow:scroll make a difference when you try to reset scrollTop?